# How to I add captions to this grid of images?

Tags: html, css

How to I add linked captions to this grid of images?

I currently have an old CMS which allows me to put a row of 4 images. However, on mobile, they stack in one column. I want to stack in 3 columns or 2 columns instead. The code below seems to do the trick, except I can't put linked captions underneath.

Thanks.

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>
</div>


<style>
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Where are you adding the captions?

Comment: consider to use figure tag and figcaption

Answer (score 0):

Just add the captions to the individual div elements.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>

  <div><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <p>Caption</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you don't have any captions. But you can add one in your `div` individually by doing:

```
<div>
  <img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
  <figcaption>Cation1</figcaption>
</div>
```

For example.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NOTE: The HTML <figcaption> or Figure Caption element represents a caption or legend describing the rest of the contents of its parent <figure> element.[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) SO the correct way is `<figure><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption></figure>`